# Angular 2 periodically pull real time data

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have developed an app which basically has admin and client portal running in separate ports and when an order is placed from client side, the admin dashboard should be able to get the new order shown.

Basically the view has to be refreshed to keep an updated UI.

For which i have referred the below link:

http://beyondscheme.com/2016/angular2-discussion-portal

Below is what i have tried.

**order-issue.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
const user_id = {
  user_ids: this.user_id
};

// To display the Pending Orders into the table
this.orderService.getAllOrders("Pending").subscribe(data => {
  if (data.success && data.Allorders.length != 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.Allorders.length; i++) {
      this.orderService
        .getOrderItemsByNo(data.Allorders[i].orderNo)
        .subscribe(subData => {
          data.Allorders[i].orderItems = subData;
        });
    }
    this.source = data.Allorders; //To display the data into smart table
    this.refreshData();    //For real time refresh
  } else {
    this.flashMessage.show("No Pending Orders", {
      cssClass: "alert-success",
      timeout: 300000
    });
  }
});

  private refreshData(): void {
    this.commentsSubscription = this.orderService.getAllOrders("Pending").subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
    console.log(data);   //able to see the new orders
    this.subscribeToData();
  });


private subscribeToData(): void {
    this.timerSubscription = Observable.timer(5000).first().subscribe(() => this.refreshData());
 }
```

My service(**orderService**) will get all the orders:

```
  getAllOrders(status) {
   let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post(`${BASE_URL}/orders/getAllOrdersWithItems`, { status: status }, { headers: headers })
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Comment: To achieve this you may need to use WebSocket for real-time data update.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i am able to fix it with below change.

```
//Function which refreshes the data in real time without page refresh
private refreshData(): void {
this.commentsSubscription = this.orderService.getAllOrders("Pending").subscribe(data => {
    this.source = data.Allorders;   //Updated here! and it worked
    console.log(this.source);
    this.subscribeToData(); //On success we call subscribeToData()
  });
 }
```